# How to change '2017-02-20 09:57:08.512534+00' format to "dd/MM/yyyy" in java?

Tags: java, datetime

Hi I have time string format : 2017-02-20 09:57:08.512534+00

How to change above format to "dd//MM/yyyy" format in java?

Comment: This must be a duplicate but oddly I can't find anything.

Comment: Basil Bourque, the asker’s string doesn’t have a `T` in it, so it’s not exactly ISO-8601, just close.

Answer (score 2):

Convert String to date object using parse method
then format date object using format method as per your requirement

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = format1.parse("2017-02-20 09:57:08.512534+00");
System.out.println(format2.format(date));
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `Date` are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself the favour of using the Java 8 `java.time` classes if you can use Java 8:

```
    String dateTime = "2017-02-20 09:57:08.512534+00";
    String date = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSx"))
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    System.out.println(date);
```

This prints

```
20/02/2017
```

At face value it looks pretty much the same as the version using the now obsolete classes (`Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`). Still. For one thing, for your own good you will want to learn to use the new classes, not the legacy ones. Also, if some day you want to something else with the date than just convert from one string representation to another, the versatility and wealth of options of `LocalDateTime` and friends is likely to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = format.parse(myString);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But I am getting "java.text.ParseException".
I am doing below way to do it:
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date date = formatter.parse(updatedTime);
            return simpleDateFormat.format(date);